# rails twilio api release number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I use twilio gem and I do not know how to release the phone number.
I try:

```
@client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.delete(:phone_number => phone_number)
```

but rails say:

```
undefined method `delete' for #<Twilio::REST::IncomingPhoneNumbers:0x7f35c99e93e0>
```

How to correct release number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found solution:

```
@client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.list({:phone_number => phone_number}).each do |n|
  num = @client.account.incoming_phone_numbers.get(n.sid)
  num.delete
end
```

Comment: Don't think you need the extra get here, you should just be able to do n.delete

Answer (score 1):

Using the 5.x gem version and the new Twilio API's you have two options:

**If you know the Number SID**

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN)
number = client.api.account.incoming_phone_numbers(PHONE_SID).fetch
number.delete
```

**If you only know the phone number**

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_TOKEN)
client.incoming_phone_numbers.list(phone_number: PHONE_NUMBER).each do |number|
  number.delete
end
```

Hope this helps new readers using the latest gem versions.